# Convert JPG image to a texture/sprite in WebGL

Tags: c#, webgl, unity-webgl

I’m building an app in WebGL, where one of the required feature is to be able to take an image from your computer and put that image onto a card.

The file upload process is working perfectly and I can convert that image into a texture and then into a sprite and apply it to the card.

Here is the code used when the file uploader process has been completed and I have a sprite I can use.

```
    IEnumerator UploadImage(string path)
    {
            // This is where the texture will be stored.
        Texture2D texture;
                
        // using to automatically call Dispose, create a request along the path to the file
        using (UnityWebRequest imageWeb = new UnityWebRequest(path, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET))
        {
    // We create a "downloader" for textures and pass it to the request
            imageWeb.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerTexture();
                        
            // We send a request, execution will continue after the entire file have been downloaded
            yield return imageWeb.SendWebRequest();
                        
            // Getting the texture from the "downloader"
            texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)imageWeb.downloadHandler).texture;
        }

    // Create a sprite from a texture and pass it to the selected card   image
        _uploadedImageSprite = Sprite.Create(
            texture, 
            new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), 
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        // Print image filename    
        Debug.Log("Selected File Name: " + Path.GetFileName(path));
        string imageName = Path.GetFileName(path);        

        CardEditor.Instance.OnImageUploaded(_uploadedImageSprite, imageName);      
    }
```

The issue I’m having is that this app is multiplayer (I’m using Mirror for the networking processes). So I need to synchronize the new image to all the connected clients. Note that these images are not in the project when the project is built.

To achieve this, once the image has been uploaded from the user computer I save it in a folder on my Linux VM, I then initiate a command to all the clients to tell them the image has changed and is now available, so all clients ask the server for the new image to apply it to the card.

That process is working, I’m correctly receiving the image from the server. I’ve saved it onto my computer and I can open it no problem. But I’m unable to convert this byte array into a texture and the into a sprite to apply it to the card.

I’ve tried in both my editor and in a browser tab.

Here is the code pertaining to the issue I’m having.

```
    [Client]
    public void NotifyImageUploadComplete(ImageUploadIDMessage message)
    {
        
        Debug.Log("Dowload ID = " + message.downloadId + " Last Download ID = " + lastDownloadId);
        if (isImageUploadComplete || message.downloadId <= lastDownloadId)
            return;

        // Update the lastUploadId to avoid processing duplicate notifications
        lastDownloadId = message.downloadId;
        Debug.Log("Received all image chunks");
        Debug.Log("Number of chunks = " + receivedChunks.Count);
        // Image upload is complete, reconstruct the image
        byte [] downloadData = receivedChunks.SelectMany(chunk => chunk).ToArray();
        

        // Mark image upload as complete
        isImageUploadComplete = true;

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        texture.LoadImage(downloadData);

        // Create a sprite from the texture
         Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), 
new   Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        sprite.name = _currentPhotoName;
        Debug.Log("Sprite name = " + sprite.name); 
        _myPhoto.sprite = sprite;
        // Start a coroutine to reset the upload status after a short delay
        if (!isProcessingImageUpload)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ProcessImageUploadComplete());
        }

        
    }
```

If you need any more info regarding the problem, please message me. I've been trying to fix this issue for a while.

At first I thought it might be related to my byte array not being of a type supported for the texture.LoadImage, but after some test I know it's a proper JPG byte array.

Maybe it's an issue related to the way the image is received in a browser, but I've tried it in the Unity Editor too and it's not working either.

I've tried creating a texture with the default values, didn't work.
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);

I'm not getting any error message about the texture.LoadImage or the Sprite.Create, but both are empty.

Comment: Try comparing the original byte[] that the client uploads to the byte array downloaded.  Server might be altering it in some way.

Comment: The byte[] i'm receiving from the server is a valid jpg file. I can save it on my computer and open it and the correct image is displayed. It's converting that byte[] into a texture that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Nevermind I think you are right, I've printed the whole array in binary both for the array on the server and the one I'm receiving and the received one doesn't end with the value that would indicate the end of a jpg file. So something is lost in the send process

Comment: Im curious if maybe this [EncodeArrayToJpg](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeArrayToJPG.html) would work.  You could try encoding before uploading to the server.  If that doesn't work, try encoding on the client end after downloading.   You need the uncompressed data, from the original texture use {Texture2D}.GetRawTextureData().